# Chrome image in iframe not resizing

Tags: html, css, size, scaling

I'm working on a file sharing service, and am getting this weird behaviour from chrome, but not from firefox:
There is an image hosted on my server, and I'm trying to use it in an iframe. (This is nessescary for my project) on firefox, the image shows up correctly sized, it's scaled to the size of the iframe defined in my code:

```html
<style>
      body {
        background-color: black;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      #card {
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      iframe {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
      }

      #card p {
        margin-top: 10px; /* Add some space between the iframe and the paragraph */
      }
</style>
<div id="card">
    <iframe src="/iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <p id="desc">This is a one-sentence paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

only chrome and chrome-based browsers break. why is this and can I fix it?

I've tried using width: 100%, height: 100%, website-builders, serving a html page instead of just the image and reverted back, i've tried updating chrome, brave, edge, to no avail

Answer (score 0):

This is because Firefox and Edge each style the images differently, and you can not apply CSS directly to elements inside an iframe.

But you can achieve the same result using javascript:

```html
<div id="card">
    <iframe src="/iframe" frameborder="0" onload="styleImg()"></iframe>
    <p id="desc">This is a one-sentence paragraph.</p>
</div>
<script>
    function styleImg() {
        const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe")
        const innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
        const image = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
        image.style.maxWidth = '100%';
        image.style.maxHeight = '100%';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works in chrome, but not in other chromium browsers. Thank you nonetheless

Comment: @TheoMarcos I tested it in Edge and it worked fine.